# key type and value type of an existing Jcache

Tags: java, jcache

Is there any way I can get the underlying key and value type definition of the cache that is created by some other code? At this point of time I only know the cache name. I don't have any other information about how the cache was created.
The cache is here Jcache.

javax.cache.Cache cache = cachingService.getCache(cacheName);

Here it is casted to Object,Object.But I want to know the actual key type and value type.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a `Cache` available, you can find out the key/value types with which it was configured by inspecting its `Configuration`:

```
// assuming you already have a Cache object available:
javax.cache.configuration.Configuration cacheConfig = cache.getConfiguration(Configuration.class);
Class keyType = cacheConfig.getKeyType();
Class valueType = cacheConfig.getValueType();
```

Now, in order to obtain the `Cache` itself when using JCache 1.0 if you are not aware of its configured key/value types options, your only option is to use `cacheManager.getCache(name)`. However according to JCache 1.0 this will only work if the `Cache` was not configured with any specific types (ie `Object.class` is the key and value type), otherwise will fail with `IllegalArgumentException` (see [1]). Essentially you are caught in a vicious circle.

This behavior has been updated in JCache 1.1 (see related issue in [2]): now `cacheManager.getCache(name)` specification is relaxed and may return the `Cache` if one exists by the given name, regardless of configured key/value types. The only catch right now is that JCache 1.1 was released just a couple of days ago (December 16th, 2017, see [3]), so most probably implementations are not yet updated to allow this behavior.

[1] https://github.com/jsr107/jsr107spec/blob/v1.0.0/src/main/java/javax/cache/CacheManager.java#L200-L201

[2] https://github.com/jsr107/jsr107spec/issues/340#issuecomment-254070714

[3] http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.cache%7Ccache-api%7C1.1.0%7Cjar